# How to get data from the “Page Load Time” report via Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I can not get the parameter "Average page load time". In the documentation I don't see the description for this report.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the average page load time via the `ga:pageLoadTime` metric.

**Documentation:**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=site_speed&jump=ga_pageloadtime

Comment: is this available in G4 data API ?